# Capture a single pixel row from each frame of video and compile them together

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, directx, directshow, video-processing

I'm working on a project where I need to take a single horizontal or vertical pixel row (or column, I guess) from each frame of a supplied video file and create an image out of it, basically appending the pixel row onto the image throughout the video.  The video file I plan to supply isn't a regular video, it's actually just a capture of a panning camera from a video game (Halo: Reach) looking straight down (or as far as the game will let me, which is -85.5°).  I'll look down, pan the camera forward over the landscape very slowly, then take a single pixel row from each frame the captured video file (30fps) and compile the rows into an image that will effectively (hopefully) reconstruct the landscape into a single image.

I thought about doing this the quick and dirty way, using a AxWindowsMediaPlayer control and locking the form so that it couldn't be moved or resized, then just using a Graphics object to capture the screen, but that wouldn't be fast enough, there would be way too many problems, I need direct access to the frames.

I've heard about FFLib, and DirectShow.NET, I actually just installed the Windows SDK but haven't had a chance to mess with and of the DirectX stuff yet (I remember it being very confusing for me a while back when I messed with it).  Hopefully someone can give me a pointer in the right direction.

If anyone has any information they think might help, I'd be super grateful for it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a video rendered in [renderless mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (E.g. VMR9, EVR), which allows you to process every frame yourself. By using [frame stepping playback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can step one frame each time and process the frame.

DirectShow.NET can help you to use managed code where possible, and I can recommend it. It is however only a wrapper to DirectShow, so it might be worthwhile to look for more advanced libraries as well.

A few sidenotes: wouldn't you experience issues with lighting which differs from angle to angle? Perhaps it's easier to capture some screenshots and use [existing stitching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching)?

Comment: I originally tried capturing multiple screenshots and stitching them, the problem is perspective. Firstly, I can't look straight down, the furthest down I can look is -85.5°, the other problem is that as the camera moves, things are seen from different angles. The only option I can think of is to pan the "camera" over the landscape and just basically "scan" a single row from each frame of the video. I'd calculate the proper row to scan to account for the not-perfectly-down angle of the camera. I'll keep messing, I'm getting somewhere with DirectShow.Net.